# Convertir servicio FastApi en asincrono (async)

Tags: python, base-de-datos, api, asincronismo

necesito convertir un determinado servicio a asincrono en fastapi, porque me arroja error de timeout luego de que se tarde mucho en cargar un archivo csv. Esto sucede porque el archivo csv es muy pesado y contiene muchos datos, generando el problema de timeout y tomando demaciado tiempo en terminar el programa. La verdad no se como hacerlo y necesito ayuda. A continuacion dejo el codigo.

Codigo:

```
import asyncio

@router.post('/file-db-insert/', response_model=Portabilidad, status_code=201)
async def file_csvdata_insert(session: Session = Depends(get_db), file: UploadFile = File(...)):

try:

    any_file = f'{file.filename}'
    test_filename = os.path.splitext(any_file)
    extension = test_filename[1]  

    if extension == '.csv':

        try:

            Path(
                f"resources/files/{any_file}_file/").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
            aux_path = "resources/files/{}_file/{}".format(
                any_file, any_file)

            with open(aux_path, mode='wb+') as f:
                f.write(file.file.read())

            with open(aux_path, mode='r') as csv_file:
                csvfile = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

                for row in csvfile:

                    ult_digitos = row[4]
                    portabilidad_msisdn = row[1]+row[2]
                    portabilidad_info = session.query(
                        PortabilidadInfo).get(portabilidad_msisdn)
                    fecha_csv = '2022-04-21'

                    ## IDD ENCONTRADO ##
                    if ult_digitos in new_dict['idd']:

                        index_ult_digitos = new_dict['idd'].index(
                            ult_digitos)

                        try:
                            final_id = new_dict['id'][index_ult_digitos]
                            ## APLICAR LOGICA INSERTAR EN BDD SI ES QUE NO EXISTE PARAMETRO ##

                        except Exception as e:
                            print(e)
                            raise HTTPException(
                                status_code=400, detail=f'{e}')

                    else:
                        #print("|||IDD NO ENCONTRADO!|||")

                        try:
                            id_cero = row[4]
                            id_cero = 0
                            ## APLICAR LOGICA INSERTAR EN BDD SI ES QUE EXISTE PARAMETRO ##

                        except Exception as e:
                            print(e)
                            raise HTTPException(
                                status_code=400, detail=f'{e}')

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f'{e}')
    else:
        print("File_extension: ", extension,
              "RESPONSE: No CSV extension!")
        return "File_extension: ", extension, "RESPONSE: No CSV extension!"
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f'{e}')
return Response(status_code=HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

RESUMEN:  como pueden notar , el servicio sube un archivo csv y dentro de ese csv se capturan/filtran datos y con esos datos se procesan y se aplica cierta logica, insertando en una bdd. Ayuda por favor.

Comment: Añadir `async` no va a acelerar nada si quieres que pase todo eso en la propia función, crea una función para cada movimiento del archivo y que solo la función que la llama espere a la respuesta o puedes hacer un sistema de promesas (pero eso cambia el como se gasta la api)

Comment: @SrPanda Disculpa nunca habia hecho esto antes, podrias darme algun ejemplo con detalle por favor?. Gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0):

FastAPI ya es asincrono en sí, la misma documentación te dice eso. Pero si quieres optimizarlo para que la app sepa mejor que es asincrono y que no, puedes leer la documentación del tema. Está en español y puedes echarle un vistazo.
[Tiangolo FASTAPI Concurrency Async / Await](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/es/async/)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que rehacer el como funciona lo que estés haciendo, no has dato suficiente código para saber que hay que hacer así que te tienes que conformar con este esquema simplísimo, no puedes acelerar mágicamente las funciones lentas así que tienes que hacer de no bloqueen, eso siendo que la función devuelva un valor inmediatamente siendo *inténtalo mas tarde* o *el resultado* y ten en mente que esto va a hacerlo un poco mas lento y mucho mas complejo para producir el mismo resultado pero no te fuerza a esperar un resultado.

```
// foo() = la función principal
// letra(numero de ejecuciones) = funciones dentro de foo

// llamar a foo tarda la suma de todos porque cada
// funcion espera a la anterior, aun si llamas a todos
// con async, necesitan el return del anterio y van a esperar
<foo()> -> A(1) -> B(1) -> C(1) -> <return>

// foo tarda lo mismo que foo, pero no ni foo ni los 
// otros van a devolver un valor hasta que esten 
// completos y hasta entonces el hilo es libre de
// continuar lo que quiera que tenga que hacer
<foo()> -> A(1) -> <espera>/<return>
           A(1) -> B(1) -> <espera>/<return>
                   B(1) -> C(1) -> <espera>/<return>
                           C(1) -> foo(1) -> <return>
```

Bastante seguro de que esto no te va a decir mucho de como puede existir en el código así que te hice un ejemplo de implementación y uso ideal mas simplísimo posible, aparte de eso te recomendaría que pruebes a hacer alguna que otra cosa en flutter, que yo considero que tiene la mejor implementación de async para interfaces; el ejemplo lo hice a lo mas básico posible, así que no te recomendaría que lo gastes sin mas

```
import threading as th
import time

class Promise(object):

    def tiempo_espera(self):
        return self._t_done - self._t_prom

    def tiempo_ejecucion(self):
        return self._t_done - self._t_call

    def completo(self):
        return self.__done

    def __init__(self, foo, args, kwargs):
        self.__done = False
        self._t_prom = time.time()
        self._t_done = 0
        self._t_call = 0

        self.__kwargs = kwargs
        self.__args = args
        self.__foo = foo
        self.__ret = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Promesa 0x{0} de {1} ({2})'.format(
            id(self), self.__foo.__name__,
            'Completa' if self.__done else 'Incompleta'
        )

    def pool_call(self):
        self._t_call = time.time()
        self.__ret = self.__foo(
            *self.__args,
            **self.__kwargs
        )
        self._t_done = time.time()
        self.__done = True

    def __call__(self):
        return self.__ret

class Worker_Pool:

    def promise(self):
        def func_wraper(func):
            def varg_wraper(*a, **b):
                promise = Promise(func, a, b)
                self.__lock.acquire(True, -1)
                self.__ref.append(promise)
                self.__lock.release()
                return promise
            return varg_wraper
        return func_wraper

    def __init__(self, n_work):
        self.__lock = th.Lock()
        self.__pool = []
        self.__ref = []
        self.activo = True

        for _ in range(n_work):
            self.__pool.append(
                th.Thread(target=self.__run)
            )
        for w in self.__pool:
            w.start()

    def __run(self):
        while self.activo:
            work = None
            # Si aquire() bloquea el loop nunca
            # se podra terminar por espera infinita
            if self.__lock.acquire(True, 0.1):
                if len(self.__ref) > 0:
                    work = self.__ref.pop(0)
                self.__lock.release()

            if work is not None:
                work.pool_call()

    def terminate(self):
        self.activo = False
        for w in self.__pool:
            w.join()

run = Worker_Pool(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t_dir = 0.05
    t_copia = 0.5
    n_esperas = 10
    n_promesas = 10 * 20

    tree = []
    # tree representa una estruta de una
    # carpeta de carpetas de archivos
    for a in range(10):
        sub_tree = []
        for b in range(20):
            sub_tree.append(a*b)
        tree.append(sub_tree)

    @run.promise()
    def copia_archivo(_):
        time.sleep(t_copia)

    def crea_directorio(_):
        time.sleep(t_dir)

    tmps_ejecucion = 0
    tmps_espera = 0
    tmps = time.time()

    hit = []
    for a in tree:
        # esta funcion es rapida y no necesita ser
        # gastara como promesa y si lo haces puede que
        # la propia promesa añada el mismo tiempo que quites
        crea_directorio(a)
        for b in a:
            # esta si va a tartar y en vez de ejecutar
            # una a una, es mejor lanzarlas como
            # promesas e ir descartando las completas
            hit.append(copia_archivo(b))
            #   promesa = Funcion()
            #   -- <mas codigo> --
            #   resultado = promesa()

    print('Todos prometidos en: {0}s'.format(
        round(time.time() - tmps, 3)
    ))

    while len(hit) != 0:
        for i in reversed(range(len(hit))):
            # Si eliminas mirando en orden creciente
            # por cada .pop() el indice maximo sera
            # +1 fuera de rango
            if hit[i].completo():
                tmps_ejecucion += hit[i].tiempo_ejecucion()
                tmps_espera += hit[i].tiempo_espera()
                hit.pop(i)

        print('\rProgreso: {0}/{1}'.format(
            n_promesas - len(hit), n_promesas
        ), end='')

    tmps = round(time.time() - tmps, 2)
    print('')
    print('Sin promesa: {0}s'.format(
        n_promesas * t_copia + n_esperas * t_dir
    ))
    print('Con promesa: {0}s'.format(tmps))
    print('  - media de ejecucion: {0}s'.format(
        round(tmps_ejecucion / n_promesas, 3)
    ))
    print('  - media de espera: {0}s'.format(
        round(tmps_espera / n_promesas, 3)
    ))
    run.terminate()
```